# sending data from nodejs to client not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mailchimp

I am trying to send a status message to client via ajax call using GET method.
My data to Nodejs server goes through fine, but i cannot send back the data to my client.I am using expressjs as my framework.
I know the data exists because when I console.log(error) I get a object such as 
{[Error:test@test.com is already subsribed]} but i cannot output this message to client.

Here is the route.js: it captures (\subscribe) on app.js

```
function signUp(name, email){
    var MailChimpAPI = require('mailchimp').MailChimpAPI;
    var API_KEY = 'asdfasdf',
            LIST_ID = 'asdfasdfas';
  var api = new MailChimpAPI(API_KEY , { version : '1.3', secure : false });
    var names = name.split(' '), status;
    var data ={
            apikey: API_KEY,
            id: LIST_ID,
            email_address : email,
            merge_vars: {'FNAME': names[0], 'LNAME': names[1]},
            double_optin: false,
            send_welcome: true
        };

     api.listSubscribe(data, function(error) {

            if(error != null){
                console.log(error);
                status = error;
            }else {
            console.log('success');
                status= '{success}';
            }
        });

    return status;
}


exports.send = function(req, res, next){
    var name = req.query.name, email = req.query.email;
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "json"});
    res.send(signUp(name, email));
    res.end();

}
```

Here is my client side: (returns null)

```
$.ajax({
    url:'subscribe',
    method: 'GET',
    data: {name: name, email: email},
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(res){
    alert(res);
    }
```

Comment: Then how should the layout look like? any example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the API (mailchimp) you're using, so the solution might be totally wrong. But generally you can see the difference between synchronous and asynchronous programming. Please read some tutorials to fully understand the Node.js way, because it takes some time to embrace this kind of programming :-)

The most important thing is that functions typically don't return values, but call a callback-function (sometimes not named `callback` but `done`) when they are ready or an error was encountered.

```
function signUp(name, email, callback) { // <----- provide a callback
    var MailChimpAPI = require('mailchimp').MailChimpAPI;
    var API_KEY = 'asdfasdf',
        LIST_ID = 'asdfasdfas';
    var api = new MailChimpAPI(API_KEY, { version: '1.3', secure: false });
    var names = name.split(' '), status;
    var data = {
        apikey: API_KEY,
        id: LIST_ID,
        email_address: email,
        merge_vars: {'FNAME': names[0], 'LNAME': names[1]},
        double_optin: false,
        send_welcome: true
    };

    api.listSubscribe(data, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            callback(error); // <--- this is one of the "exit"-points of the function
        } else {
            console.log('success');
            callback(null, result); // <--- this is another
        }
    });
    // <----------- no return! nobody cares about the return value.
}


exports.send = function (req, res, next) {
    var name = req.query.name, email = req.query.email;
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "json"});
    signUp(name, email, function (err, result) {

        // this function gets called when signUp is done (maybe seconds later)

        if (err) {
            res.send(500);
            return;
        }
        // don't know what the result looks like
        res.send({status: 'success'});
        // res.end(); DON'T USE res.end() in express!
    });
};
```

Comment: hey quick question, is it okay to add return statements to functions in nodejs?

Comment: It's OK. Return values of asynchronous functions will always be ignored by the caller and synchronous functions can be treated like in all other common programming languages. You can often see `return callback(error)` even the callback function doesn't return a value other than `undefined`. This is only done to get shorter code, but might mislead unexperienced readers.